# Error: assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c

estoy repasando los apuntadores en c, hace millones de años que no los toco y necesito usarlos, repasando en el libro de programación en c de Schaum, capitulo 10 apuntadores pag. 372, ejemplo 10.22 plantean una suma de dos matrices con notación de apuntadores, en específico mediante el concepto de apuntador a un conjunto de arreglos unidimensionales. Y me encuentro con este problema el cual no logro ver o entender. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

> Suma de dos tablas de un números. Mediante notación punteros,el conse´pto a utilizar será el de una variable puntero   que apunta a un conjunto de arrays.
>
> Cada array bidimencional se procesa como un puntero a un conjunto de arryas unidimencionales de enteros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXFIL 20

// Prototipo de funciones
void leerEntrada(int (*a)[MAXFIL], int nFilas, int nCols);
void calcularSuma(int (*a)[MAXFIL], int (*b)[MAXFIL], int (*c)[MAXFIL], int nFilas, int nCols);
void escribirSalida(int (*c)[MAXFIL], int nFilas, int nCols);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int fila, nFilas, nCols;

    // Definicón de punteros a un conjuntos de arryas unidimencionales.
    int (*a)[MAXFIL], (*b)[MAXFIL], (*c)[MAXFIL]; 

    printf("¿Cuántas filas? "); scanf("%i", &nFilas);
    printf("¿Cuántas columnas? "); scanf("%i", &nCols);

    // Reserva  inicial de memoria
    for (fila = 0; fila < nFilas; fila++)
    {
        a[fila] = (int *) malloc (nCols * sizeof(int));
        b[fila] = (int *) malloc (nCols * sizeof(int));
        c[fila] = (int *) malloc (nCols * sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("\n\nPrimera matriz:\n");
    leerEntrada(a, nFilas, nCols);
    printf("\nSegunda matriz\n");
    leerEntrada(b, nFilas, nCols);

    calcularSuma(a, b, c, nFilas, nCols);

    printf("\n\nSumas de los elementos:\n\n");
    escribirSalida(c, nFilas, nCols);

    return 0;
}

// leer una tabla de enteros
void leerEntrada(int (*a)[MAXFIL], int m, int n)
{
    int filas, col;

    for (filas = 0; filas < m; filas++)
    {
        printf("Introducir datos para la fila n° %i\n", filas + 1);
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            scanf("%i", (*(a + filas) + col));
        }
    }
}

// Sumar los elementos de dos matrices.
void calcularSuma(int (*a)[MAXFIL], int (*b)[MAXFIL], int (*c)[MAXFIL], int m, int n)
{
    int fila, col;

    for (fila = 0; fila < m; fila++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            *(*(c + fila) + col) = *(*(a + fila) + col) + *(*(b + fila) + col);
        }
    }
}

// Salida de suma de dos matrices
void escribirSalida(int (*a)[MAXFIL], int m,int n)
{
    int fila, col;

    for (fila = 0; fila < m; fila++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            printf("%i", *(*(a + fila) + col));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

El error es el siguiente:error: assignment to expression with array type
Cuando se asignas los tamaños mediante mallaoc.

Comment: Podrías indicar por favor la fila en donde ocurre el error de compilación? Solo para asegurar una respuesta efectiva. Por tu descripción ocurre en instrucciones como esta: `a[fila] = (int *) malloc (nCols * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Ya lo he logrado corregir. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero me gustaría recomendarte que para una futura ocasión, reduzcas el código de ejemplo a lo que se ajuste con tu problema, en tu caso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXFIL 20

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int nCols = 2;

    // Definicón de punteros a un conjuntos de arryas unidimencionales.
    int (*a)[MAXFIL];

    a[0] = (int *) malloc (nCols * sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Nos facilita al resto entender el error y ahora, a tu respuesta!

Esto es una variable int:

```
int a;
```

Esto un puntero a int:

```
int *a;
```

Esto un array de punteros a int

```
int *a[20];
```

Pero... ¿como se define entonces un puntero a un array? ¿no se puede?

Los corchetes (`[]`) se evalúan antes que los asteriscos (`*`), por lo que si quieres que el puntero se evalue el primero, debes rodearlo con un paréntesis, que en este caso funciona igual que en las funciones matemáticas, donde te indican que operaciones realizar primero.

Esto es un puntero a un array de 20 int:

```
int (*a)[20];
```

El código de ejemplo que te he puesto (resumen del tuyo), arroja el siguiente error:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [20]'

Efectivamente, estas intentando asignar un puntero a int (apunta al primer int reservado con malloc) a un puntero que apunta a un array de 20 posiciones.

Y este es tu segundo problema, utilizas malloc para reservar memoria dinámica pero a la vez utilizas variables de tamaño fijo como MAXFIL, por lo que te resultará complicado unir ambos mundos.

Si estás reservando una matriz de ints, simplemente reserva memoria de esta forma:

```
int *a = (int *) malloc( nFilas * nCols * sizeof(int) );
```

Te tocará cambiar todos los parámetros que has definido en las funciones.

Espero que te haya ayudado a entender el motivo de por qué se queja tu compilador.

Un saludo